# JQuery on Google JSON fails with Error 405?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http-error

I am not able to understand, how to do fetch JSON data from Google servers, the requests fails with 405 HTTP error (*Method Not Allowed*). But I can download the JSON file manually or using PHP on my web server using `file_get_contents` API. But I want client browsers to download the JSON data directly. There are some similar questions on SO, but I am still not able to understand how to do that.

Any ideas?

Edit: I want to download and display this json data in Firefox 3.5

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/1783288

I can download the file by specify ?callback=? in the URL, but can't read the data then. I am open to any other method also, rather than just jquery but it has to be client side javascript.

Comment: I added the default status phrase *Method Not Allowed* for the status code 405.

Comment: What exact JSON resource are you trying to access?  Please include a code snippet of what you've already tried.

Comment: It's probably one of those services that require an API key

Comment: Hi Ryan, edited the bug, I need that json data to be fetched using javascript and display the same.

Comment: Hi Kaze, when file_get_contents can download, it means no API key is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't make cross domain request in firefox, using ?callback=?, gets the data in  the jquery but fails to return as it is not in the jsonp format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at jsonp:

http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html

Sounds like a cross domain problem that you might be able to work out with jsonp.

Comment: Possibly yes but have a look at this page with the tester - it might help.

Comment: sorry here's the link: http://personalized20.blogspot.com/2006/04/json-feeds-of-google-reader.html