# Why does Google Maps API return a 405 error?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have the following jquery snippet on my page:

```
$(".lookup").click(function () {
            var addr =     document.aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEditLocationAddr1.value + ",+" + document.aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEditLocationCity.value + ",+" + document.aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEditLocationState.value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+escape(addr)+"&sensor=false",
                success: function (data) {
                    var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
                    document.aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEditLocationLat.value = mydata.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                    document.aspnetForm.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEditLocationLong.value = mydata.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                }
            });
        });
```

As can be seen, this takes the current form values of address, city state and zip and passes them to the Google API, then parses the JSON response and populates the latitude and longitude fields on the same form. This code works fine on my local machine. But when I put it on my production server, I see a 405 error returned. After Googling 405 errors, I thought perhaps my server was forcing a POST and Google requires a GET but then I used Firebug to inspect the headers and they were definitely sent as GET.

What can cause Google to return a 405? The decoded url I am using above is:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1630%20E.%20Lamar%20Blvd%2C+Arlington%2C+TX&sensor=false

This works fine in the address bar as well.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783288/jquery-on-google-json-fails-with-error-405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to access the Geocoding API through AJAX. Please use the [`Geocoder`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) in the Google Maps API V3.

This provides asynchronous access to the Google Geocoder.

Comment: OK. I can easily try that. Why would it work on my local machine in test mode? It is still ajax is it not? Odd...